# What versions of Ubuntu Server include opensm?

Tags: networking, server, hardware

I need to run an Infiniband subnet manager. I've used opensm in the past, I liked it. Does anyone know if Server 12.04 or 13.10 include a working opensm?

Comment: Can't you install it?

Comment: I've been using OpenSuSE on servers for years. With recent versions it has become difficult to get opensm to compile or run - dependency on an old version of libstdc++. So I am looking for a Linux distro that includes opensm out of the box that I could switch the servers to. Ubuntu appears to have more better support than OpenSuSE, thus my interest in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`opensm` is installable on every supported Ubuntu version. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install opensm
```